# it should work vs it must work

Tags: meaning

I want to inquire about the difference in meaning between these two sentences:

```
The code must work perfectly.
The code should work perfectly.
```

For instance how the usage of "must" and "should" in the previous sentences will change the meaning?

Comment: Did you look up the definitions of *must* and *should*?  What differences did you find?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

English modals have a lot of shades of meanings, but to keep it simple, for this specific situation:

*Should X* expresses unconfirmed belief that X happened or will happen.  It is synonymous with *is expected to X*:

> The code should work perfectly (but we won't know for sure until we try it.)

*Must X* expresses that something cannot happen unless X happened or definitely will happen. It is synonymous with *is required to X* or *has to X*.

> The code must work perfectly (or our job isn't complete, etc.)

*Should X* can be used as a polite or gentler *must X*.